# ' No such sensor on Port S2' crash, LEGO EV3 Python

Tags: python, lego-mindstorms, lego-mindstorms-ev3

I am currently using the official EV3 Python from lego to program a mindstorm EV3.
When I run

```
while 1==1:

    print(ColorSensor(Port.S2).reflection())
    wait(100)
```

It works for a while, giving me the data from the light sensor, but after around 15-45 seconds, it crashes with a

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/robot/curtin2/main.py", line 63, in <module>
  File "pybricks/ev3devio.py", line 64, in __init__
  File "pybricks/ev3devio.py", line 70, in _open_files
  File "pybricks/ev3devio.py", line 50, in get_sensor_path
OSError: No such sensor on Port S2
Remote process ended due to signal: Segmentation fault
----------
Exited with error code 1.
```

It's acting as if the sensor has disappeared when it is still there.
Any one know?
EDIT: It crashes on the 250th sensor check, is this a memory issue? Tried different cable and different sensor

Comment: Is it possible you have a bad cable and that the sensor _is_ actually going away after several seconds?

Comment: Do you have any other MCU / Sensor / Cable you can test.

Comment: I have tried new sensors and new cables, not a new brain however. I have noticed it crashes on the 250th sensor check

Comment: RESOLVED. Seems the ev3 brick runs out of memory as everytime i call for (ColorSensor(Port.S2)) It creates a new channel just for that and treats it as a new completely differnt sensor. The Ev3 is only designed for 4 sensors not 250 so it gets a bit confused, instead i pre defined it with colours=ColorSensor(Port.S2) and then did Colours.reflection() and that worked well